# MVC3 textbox - create custom width

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I want to make my textbox's width longer.

The view that is generated, uses @Html.EditorFor which I noticed I can't modify nor I can add css style to it.

So I checked, TextAreFor and it works but it creates a scrollbar since it is a textarea

## e.g.

`@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Name, new { cols=50, @rows=1 })`

How would I remove the scrollbar? so it looks like it is a textbox? or is there another way to generate a textbox with a custom width?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CSS class with the following statement:

```
overflow:hidden
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TextBoxFor` HTML Helper method for generating a input element with a custom class like this

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class="yourCustomClass" })
```

and now you can define your custom styles in this class

```
.yourCustomClass
{
  width:340px;
}
```

Comment: Your code is fine, but my question is something else, when placing your code or my code it still creates a scrollbar, i want it to not  show the scrollbar, so it would look like a textbox.

Comment: then it is some thing with the CSS. Post your css.probably the HTML markup and relevant css in jsfiddle.net

Comment: I don't have any css. I am using exact code you posted. when outputting on the UI, the textbox control shows with multiple lines and with a scrollbar. Thx

Comment: use firebug to see what css being applied. IT is clearly a css issue.Can you post your css and html in a jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @style="width:150px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;" })
```